# Using fixed footer with Jquery mobile + phonegap on android 

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, footer, fixed

I am building a phonegap app for Android using jquery mobile and having some 
trouble with fixed footers.

Please see the HTML code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js">
    </script> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"
     data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   

    <form id="searchform" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"
    data-ajax="false">

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>

        <label for="city" class="select">City</label>
        <select name="city" class="city"></select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.city').each(function() {
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
            $(this).append("<option>Nagpur</option>");
        });

    </script>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"
    data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#help" data-icon="info" 
                data-transition="none">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="#help" data-icon="star"
                 data-transition="none" >Favorites</a></li>
                <li><a href="#help" data-icon="arrow-r"
                 data-transition="none" >Results</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="help">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"
         data-tap-toggle="false">
            <h1>Help</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

There is a long form containing several fields including checkboxes, radio buttons, select lists etc. (using repeated select lists here to simulate). There is a fixed footer at the bottom. Things work fine on desktop browsers. But when I test on my phone having Android 2.3 I observe strange behaviour. Assuming the footer is hiding the select list underneath , if I click on any of the tabs on the navbar, the select list pops up whereas I would expect a transition to a new page. This is as if the select list is getting the click event instead of the footer. This is very annoying to the user. I have searched google but haven't seen this problem reported elsewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a known bug, and I've seen at least one other question to do with this today. Take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6721

Answer (score 1):

Updated the solution yet again.

```
/* HACK: when clicked on navbar the select list underneath pops up 
    for some reason. So we just hide all content as soon as 
    we click on navbar and then show it whenever we load new page*/



         $(document).bind('pagechange', function(e, data) {
            $('[data-role="content"]').show();
        });

        $(document).bind('tap', function(e) {

            if($("body").data("hold-flag") == true) {
                $("body").data('hold-flag', false);     
                return;
            }

            if($(e.target).closest("[class='ui-btn-inner']").length > 0 ||
                $(e.target).closest("[class~='ui-btn-right']").length > 0 ||
                $(e.target).closest("[class~='ui-btn-left']").length > 0) {
                    $('[data-role="content"]').hide();
            }
        });

        $(document).bind('taphold', function(e) {
            /* set a flag to mark this as a taphold event */        
            /* BIG assumption: a 'tap' event is always fired after a
               taphold event */
            $("body").data('hold-flag', true);      
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I added following code. Essentially I am testing whether there has been click in the footer area. If yes then I simply hide the contents of the page. This seems to stop the annoying pop-up select list. Of course the hidden page contents must be restored after page transition is complete. I am not sure how portable and/or robust this code is. Would appreciate comments from experienced developers.

```
        $(document).bind('pagechange', function(e, data) {
                $('[data-role="content"]').show();
                });

        $(document).bind('tap', function(e) {
                /* find the footer for this page*/
                var footer = $(e.target).
                             closest('[data-role="page"]').
                             find('[data-role="footer"]');

                var offset = footer.offset();

                var scroll = e.pageY - e.clientY;
                var pos = offset.top - scroll;

                if(e.clientY > pos) {
                    //click in footer area
                    $('[data-role="content"]').hide();
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified 'tap' event handler. This also handles clicks in header area now.

```
$(document).bind('tap', function(e) {
        if($(e.target).closest("[data-role='footer']").length > 0 ||
        $(e.target).closest("[data-role='header']").length > 0) {
            $('[data-role="content"]').hide();
        }
});
```